# Black and white movie with an alien octopus that emerges from a sphere

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

When I was 13 (in the late 70s) I stayed with my aunt and uncle for a few weeks. One day on the tv there was a black and white scifi movie.

The only thing I remember about this movie is a scene of an desolate alien landscape with a large sphere. It reminded me of the moon's surface. There are astronauts - I think one was a woman. The sphere then opens up - almost like an orange - and the sections are the tentacles of a large (gigantic) octopus-like creature.

As I said, that's the only thing I remember about the movie, so it must have been scary to have made an impact on me.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already, and even if I know you said you didn't remember anything else, you'd be surprised! We have [a handy guide for story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028); please take a look at it, see if that triggers anything more, however minor, that you could [edit] in. Every info helps! Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks @Jenayah, I'll take a look. 1979 was a long time ago then (and we were dealing with the near meltdown of Three Mile Island - which is why I was staying with an aunt). But who knows, something might trigger.

Comment: By re-reading your description of the scene - so it's like, the sphere was the octopus all along, right? Asking because sphere+tentacles+aliens screams [this fellow from _Invaders from Mars_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9FCq.jpg) but it's in color and it's not that large.

Comment: There is a review on this movie that mentions an octopus and it has what looks like a beholder on the cover... could this be it: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050778/reviews

Comment: @Odin1806 I'm guessing the skull-crushing part the review refers to is [that scene](https://youtu.be/-CqAszIdbcQ?t=3582)

Comment: That is just quality entertainment right there... no doubt about it... but I was clearly wrong about my initial beholder observation!

Comment: "Wait for me baby, I know where you are." *pppffft* Shakespeare  X-D

Comment: The sphere was huge. Bigger than a car huge. Sitting on the ground of a moon like planet. All dust and rocks.